# How to analytically evaluate this n-dimensional iterated integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, iterated-integral

I would very much appreciate any suggestions and/or pointers to references relevant for the analytic evaluation of the following n-dimensional iterated integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx_1\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}dx_2\ldots\int_{-\infty}^{x_{n-1}}dx_n f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\ldots f_n(x_n)$$ 
where
$$f_k(x_k) = \exp [i a_k x_k^2 +i b_k x_k]$$
and $a_k$, $b_k$ are arbitrary non-zero real numbers, and $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: your question is not of research level. You should ask in Math Stack Exchange

Comment: @Marcel If it's not of research level, what is the answer?!

Comment: @Marcel Were you thinking of the definite integral (which would be easy)? This iterated one does not look obvious to me even for $n=2$, but perhaps I am missing something

Comment: But it is divergent. What do you mean by "evaluate"?

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko For n = 1 and n = 2, I could evaluate it and the answer is finite, i.e. the integral is not divergent! If it helps you, think of it in a distributional sense, and regularize it by adding in the exponential $-\eta_k x_k^2$ and in the end take $\eta_k$ to $0+$.

Comment: Its not divergent. If $a$'s and $b$'s are supposed to be large, you could think about a stationary phase approximation. I doubt it has an analytic evaluation in general. What I meant previously is that being non-obvious doesn't make it research level, I think. But I could be wrong, I guess.

Comment: @Andrea Becker: that was exactly what I asked: in what sense do you want to understand your integral? Only absolutely convergent integrals are defined unambiguously. This one is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Using the paper by Plackett at http://www.jstor.org/stable/2332716?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents (which, in particular, contains a reference to Schlafli) and a regularization of the kind you mentioned, one may be able to obtain a recursion reducing your $n$-fold integral to ones over sectors of smaller dimensions.